# irreducible representations of O(2) - reference?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a list of the irreducible representations of O(2). Could someone please provide a reference?

EDIT: I am particularly interested in the representations on IR^2 (irreducible or not)

Comment: Real or complex?

Comment: For SO(n,C), see Theorem 2 here: http://books.google.com/books?id=Mi1fy70II8cC&pg=PA221

Comment: If you are interested in complex irreps, then the book mentioned in the (deleted) answer by mathphysicist has the answer: it is Theorem 11.3, except that as stated the theorem is not right because it fails to mention that this is true for complex irreps.

Comment: @mathphysicist: I would undelete your answer and simply point out the above "caveat".


Comment: @Jose: I've just undeleted the answer.  

Answer (score 4):

*I just see now, that the issue is appearently real representations. I consider complex representations. I not experienced with real representations and whether my strategy works there as well.*

You can induce from $SO(2)$. Define on $SO(2)$ the rep $\epsilon_n: \theta \mapsto e^{i \theta n}$. Let $\rho_n$ be the induced one, then $\rho_n$ is irreducible if $n \neq 0$. You have $\rho_n \cong \rho_{-n}$ and $\rho_{0} = 1 \oplus det$. These are up to isomorphism all irreducible representations.

Reference: Traces of Hecke operator by Knightly and Li.

A proof also is in my thesis: http://ediss.uni-goettingen.de/bitstream/handle/11858/00-1735-0000-000D-F074-7/palm.pdf?sequence=1 on pg 101.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into [this section](http://books.google.com/books?id=7bFIgtNkG8AC&pg=PA215) of the book *Group theory in physics*
 by Wu-Ki Tung to begin with.

**EDIT**: Theorem 11.3 from this book works for complex irreps only (see Jose's comments to the answer and to the question).

Comment: This books contains the assertion that all irreps of SO(2) are one-dimensional.  So reader beware...


Comment: @Jose: Thanks for pointing this out. I guess I'd then better remove my answer.

Comment: @Jose: I hope the answer is OK now. If it isn't, please feel free to correct me.